# js: How to filter object keys from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, javascript-objects

I have an array similar to this one

```js
let array = [
  {
    name: "1-name",
    age: 18,
    direction: "jsjs"
    phone: 7182718
  },
  {
    name: "2-name",
    age: 38,
    direction: "jsjsjs"
  },
  {
    name: "3-name",
    age: 58,
    direction: "jsjsjsjs"
  }
]
```

and i want to filter it based on its keys to get an array like this

```js
[
  {
    name: "1-name",
    direction: "jsjs"
  },
  {
    name: "2-name",
    direction: "jsjsjs"
  },
  {
    name: "3-name",
    direction: "jsjsjsjs"
  }
]
```

Can you please help me i've try to solve it with no success

Comment: use array.map and return objects with only the needed keys

Comment: `array.map(({name, direction}) => ({name, direction}))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can you the array `map` function.

See an example here:

```js
const arr = [
   {
      name: "1-name",
      age: 18,
      direction: "jsjs",
      phone: 7182718
  },
  {
      name: "2-name",
      age: 38,
      direction: "jsjsjs",
      phone: 7182718
  },
  {
     name: "3-name",
     age: 58,
     direction: "jsjsjsjs",
     phone: 7182718
  }
]

const result = arr.map(({ name, direction }) => {
 return {
    name, 
    direction
 };
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You Can Try This Code:

```
let newArr = [];

array.forEach((e) => {
  newArr.push({ name: e.name, direction: e.direction });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The `map` method will work. How you implement this depends on whether you want to create a new array `result` with the previous objects deleted, or simply return the ones you want to keep. *This will create a new array* your original array will remain unaffected.

```
array.map(function (result) {
  delete result.age;
  delete result.phone;
});
console.log(result)
```